# Checkbox in JTable is invisible

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

In my jtable, I can create checkboxes by returning boolean.class value, but the checkboxes are not visible by defualt. The column appears to be empty, but when I click on each cell, only then I can see the checkbox, and after one click, the cell looks empty again.

Code:

```
public class DocTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableColumnModelListener
{
   public DocTableModel()
   {
super();
    }

public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
  switch (c) {
    case 0: return Boolean.class;
    default: return String.class;
  }   
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
return columnIndex == 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Add some more details on how you defined your JTable, for the code you put in here it seems that the row will only in editable state if you click on the 0-indexed column, then it seems correct that the checkboxes wouldn't appear if you didn't click anything.

Comment: Consider making a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the specific problem to get better answer and also to make a good question :)

Comment: `I can create checkboxes by returning boolean.class value` - are you storing Boolean values in the TableModel?

Comment: @camickr yes, this is in tablemodel

Comment: So post your `SSCCE` that shows how you are doing this. You were asked to do this over an hour ago.

Comment: @prmottajr What should I do to make them visible by default ? When I set isCellEditable to false, it doesnt show the checkbox at all. Please help

Comment: @user2945142 if you set it to false it shouldn't show that is correct. But did you try to put it to true?

Comment: @prmottjar If i set it to truw then all the cells would be editable.I want only the column(0) to be editable, so the checkboxes can be checked/unchecked.